# Forcing video to take 100% width of div

Tags: css, html, video

Currently developing a [portfolio theme](http://nuferdan.com) for a friend and trying to create a video background in the hero area.

Currently, it appears the video is only taking its natural width, is there any way to force this to stretch to fill 100% of the div? I'm not worried about quality, it's blurred anyways.

I'm using [videoBG](http://syddev.com/jquery.videoBG/) to embed the video content, and the following styles are applied to the containing div:

```
#hero    {
    min-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was actually the 100% height that I was applying to the video that was throwing it off in the first place. Changing this to auto let the video stretch while setting overflow to hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use that:

```
#hero { /* div filled by video */
   position:relative;
   /* other properties ... */
}
#video { /* video div */
   display:block;
   position:absolute;
   left:0;
   top:0;
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Currently have it styled like this, the video doesn't seem to budge and the supporting content has now disappeared because of the positioning I believe.